# Problem about average of cos square (nt) where n is arbitrary

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, signal-processing, average

I often see people just say time average of cos^2(nwt) is 1/2, I want to know in what cases this is not valid? w is just the frequency, can be assumed as a constant.

Assuming you are always integrating over whole number of period, then it's always to give  1/2?

What if i only integrate up to 1/2? a quarter ? 1/3? or period, will the answer be different..

Also does the n in the expression i gave affect the outcome ?

Answer (score 1):

When averaging a periodic function, you must always take a complete period, no more, no less. Otherwise, it will give a biased estimate of the average. The n does not affect the outcome because $\displaystyle \sin(2n\omega t)$ is always 0 when $t=T$, where T is the period of oscillation.

The $\displaystyle \sin(2n\omega t)$ arises because of this:

Average $\displaystyle = \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T \cos^2{(n\omega t)}dt\\\displaystyle =\frac{1}{2T}\int_0^T(\cos{(2n\omega t)} + 1)dt\\\displaystyle  = \frac{1}{2T}.(\frac{1}{2}\sin{(2n\omega T)} + T)\\\displaystyle  = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Thank you so much, can you tell me how you express Period in terms of n and w??  Cheers

Comment: Nothing much to add, really. $\displaystyle \omega = 2\pi f = \frac{2\pi}{T}$ by definition, so that gives $\displaystyle \sin(2n\omega T) = \sin(4n\pi)=0$.